# Calling table valued function twice. Could be once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use in SQL a function which returns a table

At this moment I have:

```
SELECT
K.ID, 
(SELECT A from dbo.TableFunction1 (K.ID,0,77)) AS A,
(SELECT B from dbo.TableFunction1 (K.ID,0,77)) AS B
FROM K
```

I'm worried because I execute the same function with the same parameters twice, once to get one column and next time to get another column.

It turns out I can't do:

```
SELECT
K.ID, 
(SELECT A,B from dbo.TableFunction1 (K.ID,0,77))
FROM K
```

as I get: **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

Could this query be improved so I called the function only once?

Comment: @Serpiton . . . The question is about fetching two different values from the table valued function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `cross apply`:

```
select K.ID,  tf1.A, tf1.B
from K cross apply
     dbo.TableFunction1(K.ID, 0, 77) tf1
```

Comment: Great, it works! I must now research this CROSS APPLY thing more :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 things here:

- Use cross apply

  ```
  select k.id, f.b, f.b
    from k
   cross apply dbo.TableFunction(k.id, 0, 77)
  ```

This will work fine if your query stays that simple, but if you start to have other joins, that limit the number of rows that you would return from "K", then you can still end up running "TableFunction" on every row in "K".  I've seen that turn into a performance nightmare.

- Convert the function to a 2 scalar functions

  ```
  select
  K.ID, 
  dbo.ScalarFunctionA (K.ID,0,77)) AS A,
  dbo.ScalarFunctionB (K.ID,0,77)) AS B
  FROM K
  ```

This also has drawbacks if you have a big query within that function, you're now running that query twice for every row you return.  If you're only returning 1 row, no problem, if you're returning thousands performance takes another hit.

- Unwrap the function completely and include it within the query.  Most likely the fastest, but comes with the drawback of not reusing the code.